# UISearchBar using prepareForSegue

Tags: ios, search, searchbar

I´m doing a small project, and I got a problem. I have a UITableView with a UISearcBar. Everything works fine and the search gives me correct result´s, but now I want to use the prepareForSegue method in order to go to a detailViewController for each search result.

eg. if I search for product "A", and found it, when choose that produt it goes for a ViewController_A, if I search and chose product "B" it should go for ViewControler_B.

At this moment, with this code no mather what i choose, it always go to the same Viewcontroller.

```
#pragma mark - TableView Delegate
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Perform segue to candy detail
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"candyDetail" sender:tableView];


}

#pragma mark - Segue
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"candyDetail"]) {
        UIViewController *candyDetailViewController = [segue destinationViewController];



        // In order to manipulate the destination view controller, another check on which table (search or normal) is displayed is needed
        if(sender == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
            NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
            NSString *destinationTitle = [[filteredCandyArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] name];
            [candyDetailViewController setTitle:destinationTitle];
        }
        else {
            NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
            NSString *destinationTitle = [[candyArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] name];
            [candyDetailViewController setTitle:destinationTitle];
        }

    }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're always invoking the same segueId, "candyDetail".

Instead, you should have two manual segues hooked up in your `UIStoryBoard`, each pointing to different scenes (one with an id of "showViewControllerA" going to `ViewControllerA` and the other "showViewControllerB" pointing at `ViewControllerB`). Then you can do the following:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([[self.candyArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isKindOfClass:[CandyA class]]) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showViewControllerA" sender:self];
    } else if ([[self.candyArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isKindOfClass:[CandyB class]]) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showViewControllerB" sender:self];
    };
}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showViewControllerA"]) {
        ViewControllerA *viewControllerA = [segue destinationViewController];
        // configure viewControllerA here...
    } else if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showViewControllerA"]) {
        ViewControllerB *viewControllerB = [segue destinationViewController];
        // configure viewControllerB here...
    }
}
```

Another alternative is you can wire up action segues directly to different cells, and switch the cell type you dequeue in `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` based on the candy type in your source array. Either way, you'll need two segues pointing to the different scenes.

Comment: Thanks. And if i have N items I have to create N Viewcontroller´s right? Because i give you the example using only two items, but in this project there will be maybe 20 items.

Comment: You don't need N view controllers for N items - you could service all 20 items just fine with a single destination scene. Your original question asks how to launch _different_ destination view controller classes based on the row selected. If it's just the attributes of the _same_ destination view controller class you want to set (e.g. title and other public properties), your original code should work just fine.

Comment: Thanks. But dont understand very well. I have 20 itens, with diferent characteristcs, like name, size, format, date. This info is static and is in a ViewController for each candy. So if I choose Candy1, the prepareForSegue should go to VC1, and if I chose Candy 12 it should go to VC12.  So I need to make somewhere a match between the selected candy in the TableViewController, and the detail VC.

Comment: For that design my answer is correct: you need a different segue to each view controller scene. _However_, the issue is this: "info is static and is in a ViewController for each candy". It would be much better to hold your candy info as an array of model or `NSDictionary` objects and have a single segue + view controller with a public `candy` property that you set in `-prepareForSegue`, configuring the destination view controller in it's `-viewWillAppear`. See the 2011 WWDC video on [Introducing Interface Builder Storyboarding](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/) to learn more.